# destroy method on Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial Chapter 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, destroy

I'm going through Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, now I'm at the Chapter 10 and I cannot understand one thing:

When you delete one Micropost, **where is the `@micropost` variable in the `destroy` method defined?**
<sub><sup>(I suspect it may be server by the `link_to` method, but I'm not sure if that makes sense or not)</sup></sub>

#### **View**:

```
<%= link_to "delete", micropost, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
```

#### **Microposts controller**:

```
def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        @feed_items = []
        render 'static_pages/home'
    end
end

def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
end
```

#### **StaticPages controller**:

```
  def home
      if logged_in?
          @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
          @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
      end
end
```

(for whose not familiar with the tutorial, the form and the index of the Microposts are in the `root_page`, handled by `static_pages`)

if there is some code missing, here is the full project:
https://github.com/Salomanuel/Odin_Project-Ruby_on_Rails_Tutorial/tree/13-user-microposts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, while doing some exercises I found out the solution. 
Turns out the `@micropost` variable was assigned by a private method called by a `before_action`:

#### Microposts controller:

```
before_action :correct_user,        only: :destroy   

private
    def correct_user
        @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
        redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end
```

but still, is this considered good practice?

Comment: The is part of Rails convention. It's the same as using a before_action to find the micropost before the show, edit, update and destroy actions. In this case, you're calling the correct_user method before you call the destroy action to make sure the micropost exists before trying to destroy it.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing the code here https://github.com/Salomanuel/Odin_Project-Ruby_on_Rails_Tutorial/blob/375b4d7995d54337407f1736df0e7693a9de5ac6/app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb

You see at the top in the controller there is a line
`before_action :correct_user, only: :destroy`

This line tell rails that call `current_user` function before calling `:destroy`.

Now see in `correct_user` function we are getting `id` from `params` and declaring the `@micropost` variable.

```
def correct_user
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
  redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
end
```

Hope this answer your question. You can read more about callbacks from here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html.